# What is the relevance of the underlying conditions for Linear Regression?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, residuals, assumptions

It is a fact that ***Linear Regression has certain underlying conditions*** that need to be taken care of. However, one striking question that comes across my mind when I say this is; ***WHEN?*** In ***what context*** are these conditions relevant? For example, in as many as 3 books that dwell on Linear Regression (which I have read, of course there are more), either mention the conditions briefly or completely ignore those. Those books are; Think Stats (2nd edition) by Allen B. Downey, Data Science from Scratch by O' Reilly, and Introductory Statistics from OpenStax.

I was faced with this issue while working on a project for which ***my aim is to make predictions.*** Must I pay attention to the underlying conditions for Linear Regression? If yes, then which conditions weigh more than others? If I ignore those conditions and straightaway make predictions, what will be its statistical implications?

Comment: @RichardHardy , Yes, I mean assumptions. Okay I'll do what you suggested

Comment: See [these threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regression%2bassumptions?tab=Votes).